# how to carry out this comma seperated list in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

Suppose a dataset contains 2 fields : fields, question time

```
            fields                                 question time

php,error,gd,image-processing                               1235000501
php,error,gd,image-processing                               1235000551 
lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure                              1235000177
lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure                              1235001545
lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure                              1235002457
lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure                              1235002809
lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure                              1235003266
lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure                              1235007817
lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure                              1235007913
lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure                              1235020626
lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure                              1235040652
```

I tried the below code

```
DEFINE UnixToISO org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.UnixToISO();
A= LOAD '/user/home/book3.csv' using PigStorage() as (fields:chararray,question time:long);
B= foreach A generate fields,UnixToISO(question time * 1000 ) as temp;
DUMP B;
```

No change same as input

```
C= foreach B generate fields, ToDate(temp) as date_time;
DUMP C;
```

No change same as input

```
D= foreach C generate fields, GetHour(date_time) as hour;
DUMP D;
```

No change same as input.What is error in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the sample data is not formatted correctly.Check the delimiter that separates the data in the two columns.I took the sample data and removed spaces between the column data and replaced them with a single tab.In that way I was able to load two columns of data and extract the timestamp and get hour.
See below script and output.

**Script**

```
A = LOAD 'test4.txt' using PigStorage('\t') AS (fields:chararray,question_time:long);
B = foreach A generate fields,ToDate(question_time * 1000 ) as temp;
C = foreach B generate fields, GetHour(temp) as hour;
DUMP C;
```

[image: TimeStamp to Date]

[image: Date to Hour]

Comment: thanks for help.. i have doubt when i loaded as csv file mentioned above in my question , my code didnot work. but , when i saved as text(tab delimited) and loaded into HDFS , your code works.. thus, i got answer. why it is like that? can u explain usage of delimiter because though my flow of code is ok but, am doing mistakes in loading part. any ideas or precautions possible to avoid this..    thanks in advance .

Comment: I have used tab as the delimiter since I replaced all the spaces with tab.So in the load statement using PigStorage, I have use tab. i.e. PigStorage('\t'),if the file is space delmited then you would use PigStorage(' ').If it is comma then PigStorage(',').